# How to check if zip file contains all images file without unzipping on server

Tags: php, unzip, zip

I want to check if all files in zip are images or not, till now i have come up with this solution

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('CQN.zip');

if ($res) {

    $legitImage=explode('.',$zip->statIndex(0)['name']);
    if($legitImage[1] !='jpg')
    {
        // just stop processing
    }
}
```

I just want to loop every file in zip for images, if image is not found than just echo the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$za = new ZipArchive(); 

$za->open('theZip.zip'); 

for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){ 
    $stat = $za->statIndex( $i ); 

     $ext = pathinfo(( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL ), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

     echo $ext;
     echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

This I'm adding array of $ext from FOR loop, take array ouside loop and you can manipulate with that array depend what you wont.

```
<?php
$array = array();


$za = new ZipArchive(); 

$za->open('theZip.zip'); 

for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){ 

   $stat = $za->statIndex( $i ); 

     $ext = pathinfo(( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL ), PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

     $array[] = $ext;

}
print "For: ".count($array)."<br />";

print_r($array);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value . "<br />";
```

}

```
?>
```

Comment: How do i check for two image type jpeg and png?

Comment: look up, I edit my answer, and I work on on that if elseif

Comment: The finelly this is the best!

Comment: I added array in second version in my answer, that array was made by for loop, and that array go out of for loop. Now you have array out of loop and can make manipulation with it depend what you need in the future.